# NoClassDefFoundError + C2DMessaging

Tags: android, android-c2dm, noclassdeffounderror

I update my android sdk last week to 4.0 (14) and I now have the following error when I try to use the C2DMessaging class:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging

Does anybody already saw this error?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

add **gcm.jar(client side)** in your project build path.